# I am not getting this notation

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

What does this notation [image] mean? I am not getting the notation anywhere, even it is not available in wiki symbol list.

Comment: at least in Latex, the command is called \asymp. This should give you a thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the notation $a_n \asymp b_n$ means that there is a constant $C>1$ independent from $n$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, 
$$\frac{1}{C} |a_n| \leq |b_n| \leq C |a_n|.$$